# Working FFMPEG settings for converting to WebM format?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webm

Can anyone give me working settings for converting video to WebM with ffmpeg?

I am on Windows 7 with the `FFmpeg git-67f5650 64-bit Static (Latest)` build from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

I've tried several settings found on google, a couple of different input formats and even "all default" settings like `ffmpeg -i a.wmv -f webm a.webm` and still ffmpeg just gives me a "stopped working" error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use VLC. It's open-source, been around forever and is great for all things ffmpeg related.

Answer (score 5):

```
ffmpeg -i xxx.mp4 -c:v libvpx -quality good -cpu-used 0 -b:v 7000k -qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1500k -threads 8 -vf scale=-1:1080 -c:a libvorbis -b:a 192k -f webm xxx.webm
```

So far these commands are working good. Using in a Win7x64 Command Prompt for best results in my experiences so far.

FFmpeg version "...a FFmpeg Static build by Kyle Schwarzt compiled on: Sep 19 2012 16:31:43"

Comment: Too bad I haven't found a full reference for the `libvpx` options yet. Note that you might have to remove the `scale` option if you don't want scaling.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i use to convert my Nikon D3100 video files to WebM:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -c:a libvorbis -ac 1 -b:a 96k -ar 48000 -b:v 1100k -maxrate 1100k -bufsize 1835k out.webm
```